# Ex-muslim claiming that our prophet was being raped in his childhood by one of his cousin...? Is it true..?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, source-identification

Assalamualaikum , my name is Zaid I just saw a video in which an ex muslim was claiming that our prophet was being  raped by one of his cousin ?? and because of that our prophet when asked by omme salmah were refused to enter into makkah/madina..??
The reference of the hadith which he showed is in Al Sirah Al nabawiya sirah Ibn hisham.. The hadith is about abu sufian ibn harith and abdullah bin obay omiah who were denied from entering into mekkah.. Kindly please explain this..!!

Since last 8 months I am finding each question's answer which are asked by ex-muslims amd Alhumdolillah i got most of them some of them i need to find out please help me for it..!!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true.

The event you are referring to is recorded in [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/4631), and also in works on Seerah, such as by Ibn Ishaq and recorded by [Ibn Hisham](https://shamela.ws/book/23833/1137), [Tabari](https://shamela.ws/book/9783/1324), [Ibn Kathir](https://shamela.ws/book/4445/3392) etc.

It is regarding the time of the conquest of Makkah, when the Prophet ﷺ was marching towards it with the Muslim army. Some of his relatives came to visit him to obtain an assurance of security. Among these was [Abu Sufyan ibn Harith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Sufyan_ibn_al-Harith) - the Prophet's paternal first cousin.

The Prophet ﷺ initially refused to entertain him. Giving the reason that Abu Sufyan ibn Harith had attacked his honor. The meaning of this is that Abu Sufyan had verbally satirized and insulted the Prophet ﷺ through his poetry.

> وكان أبو سفيان ممن يؤذي النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ويهجوه ويؤذي المسلمين، وإلى ذلك أشار حسان بن ثابت في قصيدته المشهورة: هجوت محمدا فأجبت عنه ... وعند الله في ذاك الجزاء
>
> Abu Sufyan was among those who had insulted and satirized the Prophet ﷺ and the Muslims, and Hassan bin Thabit pointed towards this in his famous poem: "You satirized Muhammad, but I replied on his behalf, And there is reward with Allah for this." ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/223-225))
>
> <sup>— [Al-Isabah fi tamyiz al Sahabah](https://shamela.ws/book/9767/3684)</sup>

Some anti-Islamic polemicists seem to be misrepresenting this as innuendo for sexual assault. However this is a baseless and false accusation. There is no support for such an interpretation linguistically nor is there any mention of such an event in any other text.

Anyways, Abu Sufyan ibn Harith was eventually forgiven by the Prophet ﷺ, he accepted Islam and became a good Muslim and he was among those who remained steadfast in the battle of Hunain ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2874) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1775a)).

---

**Ref:**

IslamQA: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/329407/

Islamweb: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/130414/

> وقد كان أبو سفيان بن الحارث وعبد الله بن أبي أمية بن المغيره قد لقيا رسول الله ص بنيق العقاب، فيما بين مكة والمدينة، فالتمس الدخول على رسول الله، فكلمته أم سلمة فيهما، فقالت: يا رسول الله، ابن عمك وابن عمتك وصهرك، قال: لا حاجة لي بهما، أما ابن عمي فهتك عرضي، وأما ابن عمتي وصهري فهو الذي قال بمكة ما قال
>
> Abu Sufyan b. al-Harith and 'Abdallah b. Abi Umayyah b. al-Mughirah had met the Messenger of God at Niq al-'Uqab , between Mecca and Medina. They sought to have an interview with the Messenger of God, and Umm Salamah spoke to him about them , saying, "Messenger of
> God, the son of your paternal uncle and the son of your paternal
> aunt and relative by marriage!"
>
> He said: "I have no need for the two. As for the son of my paternal uncle, he injured my honor, as for the son of my paternal aunt and my relative by marriage, he is the one who said what he said to me in Mecca."
>
> <sup>— [Tareekh al-Tabari](https://shamela.ws/book/9783/1324) - translation by [Michael Fishbein](https://archive.org/details/TabariVolume08/page/n193/mode/2up)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

AoA brothers and sisters,
Our dear prophet was NOT raped at all by his cousins. There is zero proof in the Holy Quran that this occurred, nobody else has said it at all.
Have faith in the one and only Allah.
-Amber

Comment: chatbot generated answers

Answer (score -3):

There are some accounts of the prophet being dishonoured or molested in his childhood, by his cousin Abu Soffiyan.  Some people, especially in this day and age, interpret that as rape.  Here is an example:
[image]

However, in all honesty, the word rape is not explicitly mentioned.  The actual Arabic snippet is shown below:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing in the text about molested nor childhood. The english text above is clearly written by someone in a word processor, it is not a proper translation.